# How to get around of invariance of MongoRecord in Scala

Tags: scala, mongodb, lift

Say I have a class defined as follows:

```
class A extends MongoRecord[A]{

}
```

Now I need to create a new class B, that is a subclass of A:

```
class B extends A{

}

Object B extends B with MongoMetaRecord[B]
```

The compiler would give an error like:
type arguments [B] do not conform to trait MongoMetaRecord's type parameter bounds [BaseRecord <: net.liftweb.mongodb.record.MongoRecord[BaseRecord]]
[error] object B extends B with MongoMetaRecord[B]

It seems that the class B inherits MongoRecord[A], but because of the invariance of MongoRecord, MongoRecord[B] cannot substitute MongoRecord[A]. And therefore class B does not conform to the type constraint. Any idea how to get around this problem? Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2):

You will not be able to get around the invariance but instead of having B a subclass A perhaps **make an ALike trait instead**.  You could turn A into a trait and create an ARecord.

```
trait ALike {
  // all the common stuff
}
class A extends ALike with MongoRecord[A] {
}
class B extends ALike with MongoRecord[B] {
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually the code won't probably compile because the compiler will complain that method "meta" and "id" needs to be implemented with the proper types but the idea of the solution is in the right direction.
`class A extends ALike with MongoRecord[A] with MongoId[A] { def meta = A }`

`class B extends ALike with MongoRecord[B] with MongoId[B] { def meta = B }`

`object A extends A with MongoMetaRecord[A]`

`object B extends B with MongoMetaRecord[B]`

Answer (score 0):

It's a late response but maybe someone else will find it useful ;)

```
abstract class A[U <: A[U]] extends MongoRecord[U] with ... with ObjectIdPk[U] with ... {
  self: U =>

  object text extends StringField(this, 255)

  ... // other fields
}

class B extends A[B] {
  override def meta = B

  ... // add more fields or methods
}

object B extends B with MongoMetaRecord[B] {
  ...
}
```

You can use ProtoAuthUser[U] in place of MongoRecord[U] or any other similar trait.